# Exception in template helper: ReferenceError: Posts is not defined

Tags: meteor

For some reason my app has now inexplicably stopped working in the hosted version (Galaxy & MLab). I am able to save and retrieve posts when I run on local host but on my hosted version it's completely stopped working and now I'm getting this error I have never gotten before:

"Exception in template helper: ReferenceError: Posts is not defined"

I saw that there's a new way to create collections using "= new Mongo.Collection('posts')" but that doesn't seem to make any difference.

This error seems to be happening in all 4 of my helper functions that retrieves the posts and uses Posts.find(), here's one of those functions (userfilteredposts):

```
Template.userPostsFiltered.helpers({
  userfilteredposts: function() {
  var currentUser = Meteor.userId();
  var selectedListId = Session.get('selectedHood');
  if (selectedListId == 0) {
      return Posts.find({userId: currentUser}, {sort: {submitted:-1}},{reactive:true});
    } else {
       return Posts.find({userId: currentUser,neighborhood:selectedListId}, {sort: {submitted: -1}},{reactive:true});
    }
  }
});
```

*And here is how the collection is being created:*

```
Posts = new Meteor.Collection('posts');

Posts.allow({     
        'insert': function(userId, doc) {           
                    return (userId && doc.user_id === userId)
        },

        'update': function(userId, docs, fields, modifier) {
                    for(var i=0; i<docs.length; i++ ){
                                if ( docs[i].user_id != userId) {
                                            return false;
                                }
                    }

                    return true;
        },
        'remove': function(userId, docs) {
                    for(var i=0; i<docs.length; i++ ){
                                if ( docs[i].user_id != userId) {
                                            return false;
                                }
                    }
                    return true;                
        }           
});


Meteor.methods({
  post: function(postAttributes) {
  var user = Meteor.user(),
  postWithSameLink = Posts.findOne({url: postAttributes.url});

  // ensure the user is logged in
  if (!user)
     throw new Meteor.Error(401, "You need to login to post new places");

  // ensure the post has a title
  if (!postAttributes.name)
    throw new Meteor.Error(422, 'Please fill in a name');

  // pick out the whitelisted keys
  var post = _.extend(_.pick(postAttributes, 'name','comment','address','location','neighborhood','map','placepic'), {
  userId: user._id, 
  author: user.username, 
  submitted: new Date().getTime()
});

   var postId = Posts.insert(post);

   return postId;
    }
 });
```

Comment: Probably the `autopublish` package is not installed in the hosted version and you forgot to publish and subscribe https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/publish-and-subscribe

Comment: Autopublish should be turned off no? The thing that's confusing is why this would work on my local host and not on Galaxy. I am publishing on the server in publication.js - unless you're saying by default Galaxy has some other setup and I need to remove autopublish.